# Vagrant - How change directory of a VM?

Tags: macos, vagrant

When I try to vagrant up a specific VM by its id, It gives me an error:

```
Alexs-MacBook-Pro:fullstack alex$ vagrant up 2af6232
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

vm:
* A box must be specified.
```

I think that the error is because the actual directory path is deferent that when I created the VM. So, my specific question is...

How change the directory of a VM?

Comment: copy/move Vagrantfile with your config into the folder you need and then try `vagrant up` again.

Comment: That works, thanks.